# PHP - Is there a function to only keep the first X number of letters in a string?

Tags: php, string

If i have `$word = "big words";`

How can I only keep, let's say, the first 6 letters, so it becomes:

`$word = "big wo";`

(in PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substring function is what you need:

`substr($word, 0, 6);`

- [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) @ php.net

Answer (score 3):

[`substr`](http://php.net/substr), which actually features in almost all languages that have strings.